# is it possible to modify GUI mount options?

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, mount, cinnamon, automounting

I'm using Fedora 25 with Cinnamon as a DE and I wonder if there is a way to modify mount options that are triggered when clicking on a partition name in the GUI.

[image: example]

precisely I want to know:

1. What is happening in the background after clicking this button?
2. and if there is a way to customize or modify the executed command?

PS: I know how to `fstab` but I don't prefer this solution ATM.

Comment: mount the partition and then use the `mount` without argument to see what are the option use. As for what is done by the gui to mount your volume there's probably more that you can imagine involve and it might be very complicated to determine. Maybe read the source of the app your using but this will most likely lead you to another app/deamon